# Why can't I import COUNTRIES from pygal.i18n

Tags: python, import, pygal

I'm trying to import COUNTRIES from pygal.i18n by using the piece of code below.

```py
     from pygal.i18n import COUNTRIES
```

After I run this, I get the following error.

```py
    ImportError: No module named 'pygal.i18n'.
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `i18n` module was removed in pygal-2.0.0, however, it can now be found in the `pygal_maps_world` plugin.

You can install that with `pip install pygal_maps_world`. Then you can access `COUNTRIES` as  `pygal.maps.world.COUNTRIES`:

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES
```

Whats left of the `i18n` module can be imported with:

```
from pygal_maps_world import i18n
```

Comment: Thanks so much! However I was able to use "from pygal_maps_world.i18n import COUNTRIES".

Comment: @HelpMe: that would work too! Can I direct you to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for info on how to handle answers.

Comment: For those working through the book Python Crash Course you can also get specific instructions for updating the pygal code here: https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_16/README.html

Answer (score 0):

try: pip3 install pygal.maps.world 
and then: from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES

it does the same thing as i18n module

author, hope it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
from pygal_maps_world import i18n

# выводим код страны и ее название в принятом международном формате
for country_code in sorted(i18n.COUNTRIES.keys()):
    print(f"{country_code} - {i18n.COUNTRIES[country_code]}")
```

*For example,
th - Thailand
tj - Tajikistan
tl - Timor-Leste
tm - Turkmenistan*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this code worked:

```
from pygal_maps_world.i18n import COUNTRIES 
for country_code in sorted(COUNTRIES.keys()):
        print(country_code, COUNTRIES[country_code])
```